# how to select latest record from table by using Group by statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i fetch the chat messages from table and group by according to sender id

---

### **Messages Table**

```
msg_id     msg(messages)  sender(user id)  receiver (user id)  time (timestamp)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1              hello bro             1              2                 12am
 2              hello                 2              1                 12am
 3              i disscuss something  1              2                 12:01am
 4              are you free          1              2                 12:03am

-----------------------------------------------------
**User Table**
-----------------------------------------------------
 u_id       user_name    
  1           khalid
  2           brain
  3           abdullah
```

then when i make this query

```
SELECT sender.user_name sender, receiver.user_name receiver,
       messages.time msgtime, messages.msg msg,sender.u_id u_id,
       sender.user_name user_name FROM messages LEFT JOIN user 
       AS sender ON messages.sender = sender.u_id LEFT JOIN user
       AS receiver ON messages.receiver = receiver.u_id where 
       sender.u_id<>1 group by messages.sender ORDER BY 
       messages.msg_id desc
```

but when i use group by sender then it not show latest message in group by statement it show old record

**What i want**

i want query show latest last message of every sender

Comment: I couldn't test it but maybe this shorter way of JOINing will work? `SELECT fields FROM messages, user WHERE messages.sender = user.u_id GROUP BY user.u_id ORDER BY messages.time DESC`. Secondly, your `SELECT` fields look a little confusing, e.g. why are you selecting `sender.user_name sender`? IMO, it should be `user.user_name` as per your table structure above.

Comment: Joining would not make any difference.

Comment: Why are there two different joins to user_tbl. A single join with two conditions will do.

Comment: you can do it but not with GROUP BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without grouping at all - simply by `left joining` the messages table to itself, with the predicate being the same sender, and later timestamp.  If there is no later timestamp, you will end up with null values in the second table, meaning you've identified the most recent message.

```
select s.user_name as `from`, r.user_name as `to`, m1.msg, m1.time 
  from messages m1
    left join messages m2
      on m1.time < m2.time and m1.sender = m2.sender
    inner join users s
      on m1.sender = s.u_id
    inner join users r
      on m1.receiver = r.u_id
  where m2.sender is null;
```

If you absolutely want to use `group by`, you can do it by first finding the `max(time)` for each sender, and joining that result back to the messages and users table, like so:

```
select s.user_name as `from`, r.user_name as `to`, m.msg, m.time
  from messages m
    inner join users s
      on m.sender = s.u_id
    inner join users r
      on m.receiver = r.u_id
    inner join (
      select sender, max(`time`) as ts
        from messages
        group by sender
    ) q on m.sender = q.sender and m.time = q.ts
```

Both queries will give you identical results

Answer (score 0):

You date desc order choose it.`ORDER BY messages.timestamp desc`

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT sender.user_name sender, receiver.user_name receiver,MAX(messages.time) msgtime, messages.msg msg,sender.u_id u_id,sender.user_name user_name 
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN user AS sender 
ON messages.sender = sender.u_id 
INNER JOIN user AS receiver 
ON messages.receiver = receiver.u_id 
where sender.u_id<>1 
group by messages.sender 
ORDER BY messages.msg_id desc
```

Comment: You [need to read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) to understand why this query is terrible - you can't rely on `group by` to choose the right values for fields not contained in the `group by`

Answer (score -2):

first select the recent msg from this query

```
SELECT sender, receiver, MAX(time) AS Most_Recent 
                                    FROM Messages WHERE receiver = receiverid(userid that receive this msg) GROUP BY sender
```

know this query give group by according to recent **sender msg**

Comment: that query isn't as correct as you think -- particularly `SELECT sender, receiver, MAX(time) AS Most_Recent`, as `receiver` does not have a guaranteed value, since you do not group by it. MySQL is free to choose ANY receiver to fill this value with, not necessarily the one that matches the most recent message.

Comment: how on earth have you  marked this correct? it is fundamentally wrong, for the above reasons.

Comment: dear see please what the question and i solve the question with this solution so it is right and 100% working

Comment: i see you edited it. now it doesn't even give the message, and it only gives the latest timestamp for messages to a single person, which is completely not what you asked in the question

Comment: i just need solution so i got this solution and i thought i share this one but if you don't like this i know i am new Developer my b some fault in my logic's so don't be panic its 100% working

Comment: can i ask if even tried the other answers on this page?

Comment: yes of course if you have better answer then put on this page i am very thankful to you